# Parse and Transform JSON Array of strings in sql

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, databricks

I have a table that has a column that contains an array of strings, example
`["Emily", "Anna"]`, I need to parse this array into 2 columns. 
Is there a way to do this in sql?

I have tried OPENJSON but this function doesn't work in databricks

Comment: Are there always exact 2 elements?

Comment: Yes, only 2 elements!                                                                                              If I do as you mentioned I get this error: ``` Can't extract value from first_name#17344: need struct type but got string;```

Comment: I'm using Databricks if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the array element indexes:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=587ba13da19b25336e213ee9803f9d08)

```
SELECT
    mycolumn[1] AS first_value,
    mycolumn[2] AS second_value
FROM
    mytable
```

Comment: Yes, it did help but it didn't work in databricks. I do accept your answer, because it helped me on the sql server. Thanks!